# .NET Regex Grouping: Exclude String from group

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, regex-group

when I am using a Regular Expression in .NET like

`(.+) (c b|b)`

and I have a string like "somestring c b" I am always getting "somestring c" in the first group and "b" in the second group.

I want to get "somestring" in the first group and "c b" in the the second group.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(.+?) (c b|b)
```

`?` is the lazy qualifier, which says to match the minimum number of characters required to satisfy the overall regex.

[Here is a grid of them and more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to make the first group reluctant by adding a question mark after the plus, like this:

```
(.+?) (c b|b)
```

Without that, it won't be greedy and match as many valid characters as it can, which in your case, means matching the c in that first group.

Answer (score 0):

Put what you want to match inside the parentheses, and put the "or" symbol between your acceptable matches. For instance this RegEx should do the trick:

```
(.+ b|b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it as below

```
(.+[^c]) (c b|b)
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/owZHBVcIeH)